# Outputting javascript from jquery ajax not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

I'm inserting some data into a div container via ajax. When its just straight html being loaded into the div it works fine, however when I try to insert a javascript function in script tags it causes the page to refresh and hang when the ajax is enabled. How would I insert this script into the div container via ajax?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
showtext('By clicking this link you have activated the coupon. View the newly opened Kensie window to view this deal!','coupon-23147');
</script>
```

The showtext function is contained in functions.php. This file isn't included with loadmore.php. Could that be causing the problem? Here it is:

```
function showtext(text,id) {
document.write("<div style='display:none'><div id='" + id + "'><table align='center' bgcolor='ffffff' border='0' width='450' height='180'><tr><td><font face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' size='4'><center>" + text + "<br/><br/><IMG border='0' src='http://static.mydomain.com/images/logonew1.png' align='center'></center></td></tr></table></div></div>");
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate the function on showtext ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to show some sort of pop-up/lightbox type window? If so, I would suggest not doing this, but more something like so:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "YOUR URL",
    type: "POST",
    data: {var1: "1", var2: "2"},
    success: function(data) {
        showMessage(data);
    }
});

function showMessage(message) {
    ...
    ...
}
```

That said, what was `showtext`? Can you show that function?

**EDIT**

I guess what I am saying, is why would you pass a function like this, and not just pass the text to the function... Maybe I am on the wrong path

Comment: Yes, I've shown showtext in my original post. Problem is, I'm already using an ajax call since this is a lazy load operation. On the category pages for coupons I don't load them all instantly. I'm using a ajax call to insert them as the user scrolls.

Comment: @PaperChase - What do you want to do? Load a bunch of coupons via ajax and append them to the DOM?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The entire html of the coupon is loading fine. However the javascript function that is at the end of each coupon isn't loading. This function creates the lightbox alert window when the button for "click here to activate" is pressed. Is this even possible to do? Will the browser recognize the function since it was added after the body was loaded? What about eval? Damn, should I just paginate instead? lol

Comment: @PaperChase - I see what you are trying to do. You can't insert a script block inside of another script block. Maybe set an attribute on the root element you are inserting and then read that to see what you want to do.

Comment: Its not a script inside of a script, its a script inside of a div. There must be a way to do it. How do those punks at twitter and facebook pull it off? Can I do a document.write somewhere?

Comment: Actually, I'm an idiot. I can just manually add the html that would have been written via document.write to loadmore.php. However, now my only issue is how to add the ZeroClipboard files to the coupon codes???